# Integer to Text not displaying correctly

Tags: c++

I have code that converts a integer to text and when the user inputs the number they would like to convert it displays all numbers in English text up until that number. However, If I enter any number above 10 it displays as:

Seven
Eight
Nine
TenTwenty

Everything after that works fine. Here is the code

```
void Int_To_Text(int num) {
int first = num/10;
int second = num % 10;

if (num >= 11 && num <=20) {
    switch (num) {
        case 11:
            cout << "Eleven";
            break;
        case 12:
            cout << "Twelve";
            break;
        case 13:
            cout << "Thirteen";
            break;
        case 14:
            cout << "Fourteen";
            break;
        case 15:
            cout << "Fifteen";
            break;
        case 16:
            cout << "Sixteen";
            break;
        case 17:
            cout << "Seventeen";
            break;
        case 18:
            cout << "Eighteen";
            break;
        case 19:
            cout << "Nineteen";
            break;
        case 20:
            cout << "Twenty";
            break;

    }
}
else {
    switch (first) {
        case 1:
            if (second == 0)
                cout << "Ten";
            case 2:
                cout << "Twenty";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Thirty";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Fourty";
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "Fifty";
                break;
            case 6:
                cout << "Sixty";
                break;
            case 7:
                cout << "Seventy";
                break;
            case 8:
                cout << "Eighty";
                break;
            case 9:
                cout << "Ninety";
                break;
            case 10:
                cout << "One Hundred";
                break;

            }
            if(first > 1 && num != 100)
                cout << " ";
            switch (second) {
                case 1:
                    cout << "One";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "Two";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "Three";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout << "Four";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cout << "Five";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    cout << "Six";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    cout << "Seven";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    cout << "Eight";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    cout << "Nine";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
    }
    return;
}

int main() {

int num;
int c = 1;

cout << "Please enter a number you would like to convert" << endl;
cin >> num;

    if(num > 100)
        cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 99";
    else {

        for(int i = 1; i <=num; i++) {
            Int_To_Text(c);
            c++;
            cout << endl;
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I will edit the post with more code.

Comment: You are missing a break in case 1: and some other  code.

Comment: Can you use a map instead? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: GCC [warns about this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xrPCNm) if you enable its warnings.

Comment: You said that you will provide more code.  Please include a main() function and provide a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.

Comment: @JohnMurray, There was one for a minute, but it disappeared without being in the edit history.

Comment: You should share more explanation/code about "all the numbers...until that number". Why does your example start at Seven? If they enter 18 where is your code to print Eleven, Twelve, etc.? Your question is missing a lot so makes it hard to answer completely.

Comment: At one point the code was here then removed although I don't understand the edit history. Also I don't understand how the program produced the answer that was shown.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit inappropriate but I LOL'd real hard on OP's comment "I will edit the post with more code" :D

Answer (score 1):

In the following snippet:

```
case 1:
    if (second == 0)
        cout << "Ten";
case 2:
    ...
```

If `case 1` is reached and `second != 0`, the program control will [*fall through*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough) to the next case label, which is `2` in this case. This is because you never `break` in `case 1` or otherwise interrupt the flow.

The reason this happens is that case labels are essentially like [`goto` labels](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto), which don't define a scope like an `if` statement or other loop, and the execution of different cases is not mutually exclusive. Instead, case labels merely cause the control flow to *jump* discontinuously to different locations within a `switch` statement, and without some other control flow mechanism like `break` or `return`, your program will simply keep running right through the next `case` labels until you interrupt it or the end of the switch is reached.

Give this a try:

```
case 1:
    if (second == 0)
        cout << "Ten";
    break; // exit the switch, do not continue to case 2
case 2:
    ...
```